# Call Script Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, api, callback

I need some help because my callback function, `parseMovie()` is only being called once! Despite being in a for loop which iterates it twice. I am using a free Rottentomatoes API

The output only returns one ID, and not two ID's!
And runs `parseMovie()` only once and returns the movie ID with the last movie.

Does anyone have a fix for this script running problem?

HTML CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <title>Movies</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="input">
            <p> Actor/Actress Name: <input type="text" name="fullName"> </p>
            <p> Movie 1 <input type="text" name="movie"> </p>
            <p> Movie 2 <input type="text" name="movie"> </p>

            <p><input type="button" value="Search movies" onclick="getMovies()"></p>
            <p><textarea name="output" readonly> </textarea> </p>               


        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//api key
var APIKEY = "qf54ubt95fea9n7jytr5xh6h";
var movieID = new Array();
var actor = new Array();
var actorName = "Jennifer Lawrence";
var movieTitle;
var output;

function callScript(call) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("src", call);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function getMovies() {
    for (var x=0; x<2; x++) {
        movieTitle = document.getElementsByName('movie')[x].value;
        movieTitle= cleanMovieTitle(movieTitle);
        var movieURL = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=";
        callScript(movieURL + movieTitle + "&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=" + APIKEY + "&callback=parseMovie");
    }
}

function cleanMovieTitle(movie) {
    movie = movie.trim();
    movie = movie.replace(/ /g, "+");
    return movie;
}

function parseMovie(data) {
    var titleData = data.movies;
    for (var t=0; t<titleData.length; t++) {
        movieID[movieID.length] = titleData[t].id;
        aCast = titleData[t].abridged_cast;
        sample = [];
        for (var person = 0; person < aCast.length; person++) {
            sample[sample.length] = aCast[person].name;
        }
        actor[actor.length] = sample;
    }

    for (var arry = 0; arry < actor.length; arry++) {
        if (actor[arry].indexOf(actorName) >= 0) {
            output = movieID[arry];
            break;
        } else {
            alert("spelling error of some sort! Error 404");
        }
    }

    document.input.output.value = output;
}
```

Comment: Where's the for loop that's calling it?

Comment: Hey Willma, the for loop is in the function Get Movies (for x in [0,1])

Comment: The code that you've posted is simply a bunch of functions. None of them actually get called in this code. If there is additional relevant code, then please post it.

Comment: Ok the Html code contains a button that runs the get Movie Function
I'll post it

Comment: Where is `callScript()` defined? As far as I know, that is not a native JS function.

Comment: Hey Patrick Q, it is defined in the javascript code main.js 
after the global variables

Comment: I fixed the code according to Willma's remarks but still no luck =[ 
Please anyone I tried using console log errors

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `var titleData = data.movies;` is wrong, because the data returned by the API contains an **array** of movies.

You have to iterate through `data.movies` to get the data for the other movies (and not only the first one).

See the raw JS code and JSON data returned by the API: [api.rottentomatoes.com](http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=Hunger%20Games&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=qf54ubt95fea9n7jytr5xh6h&callback=parseMovie)

Comment: I am sorry to say that <b> data is the array</b> and that part of the code runs fine.. I do iterate through the data movies .. sorry Fabian that's not the problem, but thanks for the eye to detail

Answer (score 0):

Three things that strike me as odd that might be causing the problem.

Using for…in for an array is considered bad practice, especially when there's a native forEach method and a [polyfill for ie8-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)

`cleanMovieTitle` isn't doing anything because it doesn't return a value. If you were passing it an array or object, it would pass by reference and it would be altered, but that is considered bad practice for the exact reason that it's not working. You're passing a value, the function modifies that value within the function's scope, then does nothing with it. You need to return the string and set `movieTitle = cleanMovieTitle(movieTitle);` So maybe the API isn't returning for one of the titles because it hasn't been cleaned. See [Passing by Reference or by Value](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass).

The callback may be is getting called again before it finishes running. Not sure on this one, but you could check by flooding the loop with `console.log`s and seeing whether it's the case.

---

### Edit

So I just ran your script on this page and I'm getting an error on `document.input.output.value = output;` As expected, `parseMovies` runs twice when I remove this line.  What's `document.input`?

Comment: Willma! Thank you for your thoughts because I can relate to the first two.. (I learned programming in java, python) so I'll fix those two things.. and let you know how it reacts

Comment: Willma, your post sounds very promising! Before I fix that up! That line refers to getting the document object from HTML then gets the form name within the object called input as denoted by the code <form name="input"> and it concludes with the object named output, which is a textarea object within input form of document body object.

I think the order of using document from document.appendBody and such screws up the code!

Comment: Wow, TIL. I updated the HTML to reflect that structure and everything works as expected on my end.